# touch: .bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to create bash profile when i try

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
touch: /Users/ramesh/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

I even tried with sudo

Comment: Hmm, that's unusual.  However this question is not about programming so belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a broken symbolic link file there. That is, `~/.bash_profile` is an existing symbolic link which points to a path which doesn't exist. The `touch` command can't create a new file because there's already something there, but it also can't access the pointed-to file because it doesn't exist.